# Powerapps Filter Collection By Today's Date

Tags: date, filter, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

Good day all,

I am trying to filter todays result in SQL table to a collection in powerapps. The column "dt" represents the column in sql of datetime type.

This is my powerapps filter:

```
ClearCollect(myCollectionName, Filter(myDatasource, Text(dt,"dd/mm/yyyy") = Text(Now(),"dd/mm/yyyy" )));
```

Seems like the collection is still empty even there is data for today in sql. May I know if my approach is the correct way in filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the data is likely being changed based on the client time zone. To fix it, you can update it by applying the time zone offset to the data from the SQL table, something along the lines of:

```
ClearCollect(
  myCollectionName,
  Filter(
    myDatasource,
    Text(DateAdd(dt, TimeZoneOffset(dt), Minutes), "dd/mm/yyyy") =
        Text(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")))
```

Long(er) answer: the datetime type in SQL Server represents an *absolute value of date and time*. For example, the value '2021-12-23 09:30:00' represents 9:30 in the morning of the 23rd day of December, 2021 - at any part of the world. The date/time type in Power Apps, however, represents *a point in time*, typically referring to the local time where the app is being executed (or created). For example, if I selected that value and I'm in the US Pacific Time Zone (UTC-08:00), that would represent the same value as if someone in London (UTC+00:00) selected 2021-12-23 17:30:00. Since the two types represent different concepts, we may have mismatches like you are facing. To fix this, we can either use a type in SQL Server that has the same semantics as Power Apps (for example, 'datetimeoffset'), or adjust the time when it is being transferred between SQL and Power Apps.

The blog post at https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-datetime-values-in-sql explains in more details how to work with date/time values in SQL and Power Apps.